# Strange reference behaviour in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a MVC application and in there I have added 2 references to dll class library projects which I wrote.

When I clean the solution, one of the dll files is deleted as expected, but the other one stays. Why is this?

In the project XML here are the references

```
<Reference Include="BusinessLayer">
  <HintPath>..\BusinessLayer\bin\Debug\BusinessLayer.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="DataTypes">
  <HintPath>..\DataTypes\bin\Debug\DataTypes.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

As you can see I have referenced the generated dll file in the bin/debug folder of each project.

The business layer dll is the one which does not delete when I right click on the solution and select Clean.

If I right click on that reference and click Properties the Path is set to a local file, it is in the bin folder of the project I am in, not in its own bin folder.

Does anyone know how to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Why are you referencing the files directly? You should reference the project that builds those assemblies instead. It's probably not being cleaned out because it's in use or something by the time they are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this exact behaviour by doing the following:

1. Create a new solution with 2 projects (ClassLibrary1 and ClassLibrary2)
2. Build the solution
3. Manually copy the ClassLibrary2.dll in the bin folder of ClassLibrary1
4. Add a reference in the ClassLibrary1 project to the ClassLibrary2 dll in ClassLibrary1's bin folder

Now when I rebuild or clean the solution, the ClassLibrary2.dll in the ClassLibrary1 bin folder is not deleted.

Is it possible something similar happened by accident? (maybe not exactly the same steps).

In that case delete the offending dll by hand in the bin folder, remove the reference in Visual Studio and add it again but this time pointing to the correct location.

As Jeff has mentioned in the comments, if the projects are within the same solution, add a reference to the project rather than the dll files (Add References/Projects).

On the other hand, if the other libraries are not part of this solution, I would create some NuGet packages for them which I would host on a shared folder on my network which would allow you to add the dependency through NuGet and bypass adding references to dlls manually.